# Why do I need 5 snow layers to replace a half slab?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

I can use snow layers as half slabs, but to get onto the gold block I have to use 5.

4 looks like a half slab, and 8 is a full block - so why do I need 5 and how does 5 work - it looks taller than a half slab.

Comment: You answered it yourself. The first layer doesn't count and raise you up. And since your'e answering it yourself should it be CW?

Comment: @UniKitty yes... This is a self answer... and no, self answer's don't have to be CW.

Comment: So its those questions to educate people and share your knowledge?

Comment: Yeah, maybe http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ will help.

Answer (score 1):

The top layer of snow is just graphical. You'll notice that when you walk on to one layer of snow your player does not rise up at all; it's only until 2 layers are placed that the players Y co-ordinate is effected.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the mechanic that allows you to jump up onto a block with a snow layer:

[image]

You can jump up onto both of these blocks - even though the snow block looks 1.125 blocks tall.

This might make you think you can jump up that high - but that would mean you could jump up from water to a block, as water and 7 snow layers look the same height (0.875 blocks):

[image]

In fact, the reason that you can go from a flat block to a block with a snow layer is because a single snow layer has no depth - it's like soul sand.

So a "full" snow block made up of snow layers (8 of them) is actually only 0.875 of a block - compare these 3 images:

[image][image][image]

It's not easy to tell, but I've sunk into both the soul sand and the snow layers - because the first layer doesn't raise me up.